# GitLab CI Docker Runner (macos): chmod cannot access './gradlew': No such file or directory

Tags: android, docker, gitlab-ci, docker-machine, gitlab-ci-runner

I have been trying to setup GitLab CI with a Docker Runner installed on a macOS device to handle testing on my Android project. The Docker is installed and running on the Mac and Gitlab will start the job but fails at the build stage with the error

> chmod: cannot access './gradlew': No such file or directory ERROR: Job
>   failed: exit code 1

I have tried both the Android template .yml file included in GitLab CI as well as others found online with my current .yml configuration being:

```
image: jerbob92/gitlab-ci-android:latest

before_script:
    - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=`pwd`/.gradle
    - mkdir -p $GRADLE_USER_HOME
    - chmod +x ./gradlew

cache:
  paths:
     - .gradle/wrapper
     - .gradle/caches

build:
  stage: build
  script:
     - ./gradlew assemble

test:
  stage: test
  script:
     - ./gradlew check
```

No matter what configuration I use the Runner fails during the chmod +x ./gradlew step. Is there a step I am missing here?

Comment: I guess your `/.gradle` folder which is inside `pwd` (`export GRADLE_USER_HOME='pwd'/.gradle`) is on the same folder level as `./gradlew` file, so you just use wrong path (that is why `No such file or directory` is an error). try to use something like `chmod +x 'pwd'/.gradlew` or similar syntax - hope you got the idea

Comment: Thank you for the response @krossovochkin. I've changed the .yml but still having the same issue. I have added an ls to see the current directory and this is the output.
`$ export GRADLE_USER_HOME=`pwd`/.gradle
$ mkdir -p $GRADLE_USER_HOME
$ ls
UNT-Transit-App-Android.iml
app
build.gradle
gradle
gradle.properties
libs
settings.gradle
$ chmod +x 'pwd'/.gradlew
chmod: cannot access 'pwd/.gradlew': No such file or directory
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1`

Comment: Where is `./gradlew` coming from?

Comment: I just faced the same issue. Did you check in the gradle files ->
gradlew
  gradlew.bat
  gradle/wrapper/
    gradle-wrapper.jar
    gradle-wrapper.properties
After this it worked for me

Comment: check .gitignor and your will find it disabled for upload to remote repo